# How to do a routing in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I am working on raact js POC.  I have landing page as login page and then want to redirect a user to next page. I have below code in index.js file.

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import LoginComponent from "./Components/LoginComponent";
import User from "./Components/User";


const routing = (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" exact component={LoginComponent} />
        <Route path="/LoginComponent" component={LoginComponent} />
        <Route path="/User" component={User} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  )

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I have below code in LoginComponent.js file. Thing is that I am not getting any error as well in console. When I click on Login button page posted to server and I am again getting the same login screen. I am not sure what is going wrong here.

```
import { FormGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./Login.css"
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import User from "./User"


class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: this.props.username,
            password: this.props.password,
            loggedIn : false
        }

        this.handleValidation = this.handleValidation.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }   
    //assign textbox values to props
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]
        })
    }
    //handle input validation
    handleValidation = (event) => {

        if (!this.state.username) {
            this.setState({ error: 'Please enter User Name' }); 
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else if (!this.state.password) {
            this.setState({ error: 'Please enter Password' });
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ error: "" });
            //my login service code here which is working fine. I can see a response in console.
            this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
            this.props.history.push("/User");//this line is not working. 
        }
     }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Login">
                <form >
                    <FormGroup controlId="email" bsSize="large">
                        <label htmlFor="exampleInputUserName"><b>User Name</b></label>
                        <input type="username" name ="username" className="form-control" id="exampleInputUserName" value={this.props.userName} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter User Name"></input>
                        <div><br></br></div>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup controlId="password" bsSize="large">
                        <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword"><b>Password</b></label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword"  value={this.props.password} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter Password"></input>
                        <div><br></br></div>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleValidation} className="btn btn-info">Login</button>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                    <div><br></br></div>
                    <div id="errorDiv">
                        {(this.state.error !== '') ? <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{this.state.error}</span> : ''}
                    </div>  

                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginComponent;
```

Comment: Does this.props.history have value ?

Comment: No. I have only above code. I am not assigning any value to this.props.history.  Am I missing something.. Thanks

Comment: just console.log(this.props.history) check does this.props.history have any value?

Comment: Its undefined :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **withRouter** higher order component, and wrap your component with this. It will give you the router props which then can be used to push to the route you want.

Check the docs for more info: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Hope this solves

A link to the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-1h7jy

```
import { FormGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./Login.css"
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import User from "./User";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: this.props.username,
            password: this.props.password,
            loggedIn : false
        }
        this.handleValidation = this.handleValidation.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }  

    //assign textbox values to props
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]
        })
    }

    //handle input validation
    handleValidation = (event) => {
        if (!this.state.username) {
            this.setState({ error: 'Please enter User Name' }); 
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else if (!this.state.password) {
            this.setState({ error: 'Please enter Password' });
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ error: "" });
            //my login service code here which is working fine. I can see a response in console.
            this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
            this.props.history.push("/User");//this line is not working. 
        }
     }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Login">
                <form >
                    <FormGroup controlId="email" bsSize="large">
                        <label htmlFor="exampleInputUserName"><b>User Name</b></label>
                        <input type="username" name ="username" className="form-control" id="exampleInputUserName" value={this.props.userName} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter User Name"></input>
                        <div><br></br></div>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup controlId="password" bsSize="large">
                        <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword"><b>Password</b></label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword"  value={this.props.password} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter Password"></input>
                        <div><br></br></div>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleValidation} className="btn btn-info">Login</button>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                    <div><br></br></div>
                    <div id="errorDiv">
                        {(this.state.error !== '') ? <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{this.state.error}</span> : ''}
                    </div>  

                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(LoginComponent);
```

Comment: I got error - "Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(LoginComponent) /> outside a <Router>" when using withRouter.

Comment: I have that code in index.js which I have posted in question.

Comment: @Nilesh Have added a link to the sanbox. Please refer it and let me if it worked

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-1h7jy  this resolved my issue. Thanks a billion.